# Strange behavior changing image position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am new to swift and SpriteKit.

I loaded a image and i am trying to position the image on the top, but the image is "cutted" on the top

[image: Cut on the top]

As you can see on the image, the window maxed, so it dont seems to be scaling problem.
It seems something "eats" the first 40 pixels, i am using the Iphone 4s Emulator.
If i change to the iphone 6 it "eats" more pixels on the top, is there something that "uses the top pixels like the info bar" ?

The code i am using is, something like that, on my code i loop on the images:

```
options.append(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"help"))

//Reload anchor point to top up
options[0].anchorPoint=CGPoint(x:0, y:1)
//try to position the image on the top... BUT IT CUTS MY IMAGE ON THE TOP
options[0].position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
self.addChild(options[0])

//Set the scene configuration
self.backgroundColor=UIColor(hue: 0.33, saturation: 0.47, brightness: 0.91, alpha: 1)
self.anchorPoint=CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
```

Comment: your code is a little confusing.  What I see is you're trying to position a sprite and it's not where you expected it to be.  In your code you're looping through "options" and calculating "spacingWidth."  It might help to provide a little more context

Comment: i will update, the spacingWidth just change the X position, but the problem is the Y position, i will change it :)

Comment: also, check to make sure your scene dimensions make sense.  println out self.size.  if youre in portrait mode, x should be less than y.

Comment: the sizes are correct, i even checked on photoshop

Comment: can you comment out all your anchor point code and just copy paste my code into your scene.  see if you see a red square on the top left.

Comment: i did that and no luck, it "eats" the first 40 pixels of the top, like the (0, 0) is at (0, -40) (just to explain the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're making things more difficult by changing the anchorpoint of everything around.  It makes it harder to conceptualize the coordinate system.  You should try to avoid changing the anchor point for the scene itself if you're going to be placing sprites directly on it.

Usually you'll change the anchor point when you want to make the sprite rotate around it's corner instead of it's center.  Things like that.  If you're just positioning things it makes more sense to keep the default.

This is the easiset way to make sure our scene has the correct coordinates

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.clearColor()
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
        // position sprite on top left corner of screen
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.size.width/2, y: self.size.height - sprite.size.height/2)


        self.addChild(sprite)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

try using this as a starting point.  By default spritekit is setup to use an sks file (level editor file) as a template for your scene.  I don't think you're using that.  With this code we make sure our scene is initialized with correct dimensions when its created.

Comment: I used your code and even using that it seems that there is something "eating" the first 40 pixels on the top (i am emulating an iphone 4S), so with your code the red sprite dont even appears, i changed the height to 50 to see 10 pixels

Comment: if you print your scene size out. what dimensions do you get?  try println(self.size) inside of your scene

Comment: Iphone 4S -> (1024.0,768.0).
It seems i am messing with something "stupid", my project is a game with spritekit... maybe i changed something i am not supposed to change?

Comment: i don't think these dimensions are correct.  I'm going to refine my answer

Comment: it makes the size correct, but i get (480.0,320.0) which dont seems correct, if i remove the scalemode it is corrected too, but the size still 1024, 768...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it is 480 (the retina does the "upscale job")

Comment: yes exactly.  now you have the right size.  if you leave the anchor points alone for your scene it's going to be easy to position things in a reliable way.  that red square should be sitting in the correct position now.